# PHP хранение даты в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

В таблице БД есть поле типа (datetime).

При добавлении данных там нужно записать текущую дату и время.

Если через php записать в таком виде:

```
date("m.d.y H:i:s ");
```

то этот формат подойдет для БД? или нужно его конвертировать как то?

Comment: Ясно... господа "программисты"

Comment: >Ясно... господа "программисты"

@VasyaVasya ну что за баттхерт? Неужели вы думаете, что любой человек, едва увидев ваш вопрос, тут же обязан бросить все на свете и начать отвечать на него?

Comment: @VasyaVasya 

 1. используйте стандартный `Y-m-d H:i:s`, остальное я просто не могу гарантировать, потому что не использую за ненадобностью
 2. mysql default datetime format [гуглится за три секунды](http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_MySQL's_default_DATE/DATETIME_format%3F), и не надо даже начинать про английский язык - YYYY-MM-DD понятен и без него
 3. что мешает просто поробовать?

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал TIMESTAMP, а при выводе конвертите как хотите

Answer (score 3):

Используйте формат timestamp, это намного удобнее при использовании далее.

[Раз](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php)
[Два](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.getdate.php)

Comment: согласен. всеми руками и ногами за timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Вот так тоже можно

```
$dates =date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2010-10-12 15:09:00') );
$query = "INSERT INTO timeTable(time) VALUES ('$dates')";
```